# How to extract a point cloud from Kinect recorded videos (.oni files)

Tags: ros, openni, pointclouds

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

When a live Kinect is connected, launching openni with `roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch` starts publishing point clouds at topic `/camera/depth/points`.

I have videos recorded from Kinect in OpenNI file format  (.oni). Can I extract point clouds from these videos? Is there is away openni.launch can be executed with these videos or without live camera?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194589/how-to-extract-a-point-cloud-from-kinect-recorded-videos-(.oni-files)/) by [Latif Anjum](https://answers.ros.org/users/4454/latif-anjum/) on ROS Answers with karma: 79 on 2014-10-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can find related questions here:
http://answers.ros.org/question/9150/using-oni-files-in-openni_camera-node/
and
http://answers.ros.org/question/36487/using-rgbdslam-with-oni-files/

---

Originally posted by [rastaxe](https://answers.ros.org/users/2870/rastaxe/) with karma: 620 on 2014-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Latif Anjum](https://answers.ros.org/users/4454/latif-anjum/) on 2014-10-10**:
thank you. I got the answer from the second link you provided.